# how find value of javascript variable with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, find

I want RegEx in php that find value of js variable in my html page.
Like this:

```
varName = "http://sample.com";
```

Comment: So, you want to extract the value of a JavaScript variable in an HTML page stored in a PHP variable?

Answer (score 3):

Something like that... but it could be extremely more complicated with the complexity of the js code

```
<?
$varname = "varName";
preg_match('/'.$varname.'\s*?=\s*?(.*)\s*?(;|$)/msU',$html,$matches);

if(count($matches>1)) {
    print($matches[1]);
}


?>
```